# how do you instanciate a class in c#?

Tags: c#, object, xna

I am making a game for the Windows Phone using XNA framework C#.

The main player in the game has to shoot. I have a bullet class, but how do you instantiate that bullet everytime the user clicks on the screen?

The bullet class basically draws itself and has a function called "Shoot", this is used for the bullet to move in the direction of the player.

I am a noob at c# xD

Comment: I would *strongly* recommend that you get familiar with the basics of C# itself as a language before you start on XNA. Otherwise when you have a problem, you won't know whether it's due to XNA or C# - or something else.

Comment: I'd normally agree with Jon if this wasn't game development, and learning a new language by writing a game is just so much fun!

Comment: I am familiar with the basics, is just classes am not to sure of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common method is in your game loop add in a check for the screen being touched and take action if it is.

For XNA, on the Game class (which I think is called `Game1` by default) create a field to store whether the screen was touched on the previous Loop:

```
bool screenBeingTouched = false;
```

This is to prevent multiple bullets being created on a single touch (unless that is what you want).

Then in the `Update` method of the Game class check to see if the screen is currently being touched and take action:

```
TouchCollection newScreenTouches = TouchPanel.GetState(); 

if (!screenBeingTouched && newScreenTouches.Count > 0)  
{  
    screenBeingTouched = true;  

    Bullet myBullet = new Bullet();
    myBullet.DoSomething(); // Such as render on the screen and move around.

}  
else if (newScreenTouches.Count == 0)  
{  
    screenBeingTouched = false;  
}
```

Comment: and how would you add a function to render it on the screen?
thank you for the help!

Comment: There's a number of ways you can do it, a catch-all method is using sprites. This tutorial covers the basics of touchscreen and rendering combined: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/windows/introduction-to-xna-on-windows-phone-7/

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer that solved your problem by clicking the tick underneath the answers votes.

Answer (score 3):

Not to be pedantic to andrey but technically it's

```
Bullet mybullet = new Bullet(A, B, C);
```

Comment: This answers how to instantiate a class. However there are further questions in the context of the XNA framework that aren't covered here (yet).

Answer (score 1):

If you're having trouble instantiating a class, I presume you're also not familiar with the Content Pipeline either, so assuming a basic bullet structure, I'd do something like this:

To load a Texture2D use code like this:

```
var tx = this.Content.LoadContent<Texture2D>("TextureYouAddedAsContent");
```

I presume your Bullet class has a constructor which takes a Texture2D and other parameters, use code like this to instantiate it:

```
int speed = 500;
Vector2 pos = new Vector2(50, 50); // start at 50, 50, top left
Vector2 dir = new Vector2(1, 0); // direction is in positive X direction
Bullet bullet = new Bullet(tx, pos, dir, speed);
```

Also, checkout http://GameDev.StackExchange.com, and specifically this [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9297/when-should-a-bullet-texture-be-loaded-in-xna).

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a game, I would recommend that you do NOT instantiate objects during the Update loop. You will experience very bad stutter and lag during game play because of it.

The way you want to do it is at the initialization of the game, or in the content loading stage, is to create a Queue of say 100 bullets:

```
Queue<Bullet> bulletCache;
```

Then fill that list with 100 instances of bullet:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    bulletCache.Enqueue(new Bullet());
```

In your game, when you need to shoot a bullet, simply Dequeue one of those, set it's speed, position, etc and let it render. When it's no longer visible (i.e. hit something, went out of screen bounds, etc), Enqueue it again.

This way you are not instantiating anything in the game loop and just recycling the same objects. If you do this with as many things in your game as you can, you will have very smooth gameplay. If you get in the habit of creating objects in the update loop, the Garbage Collector for the Compact Framework (the one on the Phone) will kick in at some point to clean them up and will demolish your game's frame rate.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Excellent tip, that's helped with some of my own tinkering, thanks  :)